# Cleaning data in SPSS with name misspellings

Tags: spss

I have a 5M records dataset in this basic format:

```
FName LName UniqueID DOB       
John  Smith  987678  10/08/1976
John  Smith  987678  10/08/1976
Mary  Martin 567834  2/08/1980 
John  Smit   987678  10/08/1976
Mary  Martin 768987  2/08/1980
```

The DOB is always unique, but I have cases where:
Same ID, different name spellings or Different ID, same name

I got as far as making SPSS recognize that John Smit and John Smith with the same DOB are the same people, and I used aggregate to show how many times a spelling was used near the name (John Smith, 10; John Smit 5).

**Case 1:**
What I would like to do is to loop through all the records for the people identified to be the same person, and get the most common spelling of the person's name and use that as their standard name.

**Case 2:**
If I have multiple IDs for the same person, take the lowest one and make that the standard.

I am comfortable using basic syntax to clean my data, but this is the only thing that I'm stuck on.

Comment: Is `Mary Martin` having two unique id's intentional?

Comment: Something doesn't ring true in the question description. I would expect `UniqueID` to be unique to any real individual in the population (all be it can have multiple records in this database. Why this would be the case, I don't know). I **wouldn't** expect DOB to be "always unique". Why would it? Unique against any particular individual - yes. But not across different individuals.

Comment: If you have multiple IDs for the same person how can you be sure two "John Smith"'s are in fact the same or different people in the population? How can you make that distinction? Perhaps with DOB but even that could potentially be a match. So you can't strictly speaking and so why would you want to force them all to a single UniqueID giving the impression they are the same individual? Bad idea. You need at minimum a data collection process to give an unique ID to a real unique individual in the population, which is full proof.

Comment: Because my team knows the majority of the people in the Database. And yes, this is a logging table, meaning that each person can appear multiple times in this specific table, but should not appear differently in the main people table. But before I can make each of them have a unique record in the people database, I need to standardize who they are in this logging DB.

Comment: @AndyW, no. It's a data entry error. She should only have one ID and one spelling of her name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `UniqueID` is a real unique ID of individuals in the population and you are wanting to find variations of name spellings (within groupings of these IDs) and assign the modal occurrence then something like this would work:

```
STRING FirstLastName (A99).
COMPUTE FirstLastName = CONCAT(FName," ", LName").
AGGREGATE OUTFILE= * MODE=ADDVARIABLES /BREAK=UniqueID FirstLastName /Count=N.
AGGREGATE OUTFILE= * MODE=ADDVARIABLES /BREAK=UniqueID  /MaxCount=MAX(Count).
IF (Count<>MaxCount) FirstLastName =$SYSMIS.
AGGREGATE OUTFILE= * MODE=ADDVARIABLES OVERWRITE=YES /BREAK=UniqueID /FirstLastName=MAX(FirstLastName).
```

You could then also overwrite the `FName` and `LName` fields also but then more assumptions would have to be made, if for example, `FName` or `LName` can contain space characters ect.